# Adjusting colors of the surface plot item according to the signal values in pyqtgraph.opengl

Tags: python, opengl, pyqtgraph

Here is an attempt of doing a waterfall representation.
I need to express the signal(array) values(amplitudes/levels/densities) in different colors not in shades as done.
As I'm an algorithmic and signal processing eng. and not a software developer, I'm not familiar with the color maps and these stuff. So if someone could hep me out with the code for relating the colors with the signal values.

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl
import scipy.ndimage as ndi
import numpy as np

Nf = 90     # No. of frames
Ns = 100    # Signal length

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

w_SA = QtGui.QWidget(); w_SA.setFixedSize(400, 400)

# Create a GL View widget to display data
plt_SA1 = gl.GLViewWidget(w_SA); plt_SA1.move(10, 10); plt_SA1.resize(380, 380)
plt_SA1.setCameraPosition(elevation=90.0, azimuth=0.0, distance=70)
p1 = gl.GLSurfacePlotItem(shader='shaded', color=(0.5, 0.5, 1, 1), smooth=False)
p1.translate(-Nf/2, -Ns/2, 0)
plt_SA1.addItem(p1)

Arx = np.zeros([Nf, Ns])
def update():
    global Arx
    Arx = np.roll(Arx, 1, axis=0)
    Arx[0] = ndi.gaussian_filter(np.random.normal(size=(1,Ns)), (1,1))
    p1.setData(z=Arx)
timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(update)
timer.start(30)

w_SA.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you be more specific about how you want the image to be colored? If you don't need OpenGL, here is a simpler solution using pyqtgraph.ImageView. You can right-click on the gradient bar on the right side to change the lookup table used to color the image. There are also a variety of ways to set this table manually, depending on the desired effect.

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg
import scipy.ndimage as ndi
import numpy as np

Nf = 90     # No. of frames
Ns = 100    # Signal length

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

Arx = np.zeros([Nf, Ns])
win = pg.image(Arx)
win.view.setAspectLocked()
def update():
    global Arx
    Arx = np.roll(Arx, 1, axis=0)
    Arx[0] = ndi.gaussian_filter(np.random.normal(size=(1,Ns)), (1, 1))
    win.setImage(Arx.T, autoRange=False)

timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(update)
timer.start(30)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Comment: Well, thanks a million. This representation is pretty close to what I need. The code you post is working, but:

1. I get the following error:

'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Building msvcr library: "C:\Python27\libs\libmsvcr90.a"(from C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_bcb86ed6ac711f91\msvcr90.dll)


2. It takes time to run (~ 10 sec), which will affect my app as I'm acquiring online data.


How to embed this gragh inside my QtGui.QWidget?

Thanks

Comment: 1. The 'gcc' error can be ignored, or disabled with `pg.setConfigOptions(useWeave=False)`  2. What exactly is taking 10 sec?  3. pg.image() and pg.plot() both return widgets that may be added to your GUI exactly like any other widget. See also: http://pyqtgraph.org/documentation/how_to_use.html#embedding-widgets-inside-pyqt-applications

Comment: 1. When using "pg.setConfigOptions(useWeave=False)", it gives the following error: "setConfigOption() got an unexpected keyword argument 'useWeave'". So, the 'gcc' error still exists.

2. The 10 seconds is for the window to show i.e. it stays just white window for > 10 seconds. Also, the applications stops acquiring the signal, as if the application is hanging.

3. Additionally, if I try to use any of the controls in the norm or the ROI. The applications crashes and I have to close it and re-run it again.

Comment: 1. Please note setConfigOption != setConfigOptions. 2. I would recommend profiling to find out what is taking so long (and opening a new question if it is something inside pyqtgraph). 3. Crashes should be reported on the pyqtgraph mailing list.